# What are good metrics for determining the usefullness/impact of an index in a SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, metrics

**Background**

I'm reviewing a database currently where someone applied indexes to almost everything in the database. Since we are now experiencing performance issues related to updating records, I'm trying to determine which indexes should be kept and which should be removed.

Note: I do not have access to the source code that makes requests to the database, so I do not have a complete picture as to all the requests being made to the database.

**Sample Data**

Using the query below found in the first answer in the post [List of all index & index columns in SQL Server DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db)

```
use UAT_PLUS
go
SELECT 
     TableName = t.name
     ,IndexName = ind.name
     ,IndexId = ind.index_id
     ,ColumnId = ic.index_column_id
     ,ColumnName = col.name 
     --,ind.*
     --,ic.*
     --,col.* 
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 
     ind.is_primary_key = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0 
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY 
     t.name, ind.name, ind.index_id, ic.is_included_column, ic.key_ordinal;
```

I get results similar to (This is an actual table in the database just with some values generalized)

| TableName | IndexName | IndexId | ColumnId | ColumnName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE_A | Index_1 | 183 | 1 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_1 | 183 | 2 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_1 | 183 | 3 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_1 | 183 | 4 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_1 | 183 | 5 | Col_5 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 1 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 2 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 3 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 4 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 5 | Col_6 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 6 | Col_5 |
| TABLE_A | Index_2 | 184 | 7 | Col_7 |
| TABLE_A | Index_3 | 4 | 1 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_3 | 4 | 2 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_4 | 3 | 1 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_4 | 3 | 2 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_5 | 2 | 1 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_6 | 9 | 1 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_7 | 10 | 1 | Col_8 |
| TABLE_A | Index_8 | 11 | 1 | Col_9 |
| TABLE_A | Index_9 | 6 | 1 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_9 | 6 | 2 | Col_10 |
| TABLE_A | Index_9 | 6 | 3 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_9 | 6 | 4 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_10 | 5 | 1 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_10 | 5 | 2 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_10 | 5 | 3 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_11 | 163 | 1 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_11 | 163 | 2 | Col_10 |
| TABLE_A | Index_12 | 8 | 1 | Col_11 |
| TABLE_A | Index_13 | 15 | 1 | Col_12 |
| TABLE_A | Index_14 | 18 | 1 | Col_13 |
| TABLE_A | Index_15 | 19 | 1 | Col_14 |
| TABLE_A | Index_16 | 14 | 1 | Col_15 |
| TABLE_A | Index_17 | 13 | 1 | Col_16 |
| TABLE_A | Index_18 | 12 | 1 | Col_17 |
| TABLE_A | Index_19 | 17 | 1 | Col_18 |
| TABLE_A | Index_20 | 16 | 1 | Col_19 |
| TABLE_A | Index_21 | 182 | 1 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_22 | 7 | 1 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_23 | 181 | 1 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_23 | 181 | 2 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_23 | 181 | 3 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_23 | 181 | 4 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_24 | 178 | 1 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_24 | 178 | 2 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_24 | 178 | 3 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_24 | 178 | 4 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 1 | Col_3 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 2 | Col_1 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 3 | Col_2 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 4 | Col_6 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 5 | Col_4 |
| TABLE_A | Index_25 | 180 | 6 | Col_7 |

**Question**

What are good metrics and tools that I can use to determine which indexes are useful and which are just causing bloat?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Brent Ozar’s First Responders toolkit.

https://www.brentozar.com/responder/

There is an option in sp_blitzindex to list the indexes and the last seek, scan and lookup date.